# What does it mean when you prevent a unit from attacking?

Tags: mage-knight

For instance, the Illusionist has an ability:

> Target unfortified enemy does not attack this combat.

Does that mean it doesn't deal damage, or that it does not participate at all in combat?

IE: Can I still kill this unit even though it isn't attacking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course you can kill it. That's the point of the Illusionist. The ability doesn't say "The enemy cannot combat", just that you can skip its attack phase.

I like to see it as

> "Your fellow illusionist cast a powerful spell that makes the monster
>   believe you are elsewhere. The monster tries to attack you, but
>   instead he attacks an empty space, making his attack so worthless you
>   don't even need to block. Now you can strike back and put him out of his misery!"